# sql server 2008 R2 update is stuck with sos_scheduler_yield waittype

Tags: sql-server

I found one of the application was stuck for a couple of days.

After analysis, I focused on the SQL server 2008 R2's scheduler issue.

I run the query `select * from master.dbo.sysprocesses` and found out the update query kept in `sos_scheduler_yeild lastwaittype` for a long time and the CPU column's value is extreme high (4158738),and the status is runnable.

I retried stop the application and restart it, also DBCC freesystemcache, freeproccache, update statistics on the table which the application intend to update on...

but the issue is still pending.

Can anyone tell me what the CPU column exactly mean, what the high value means and how can I fix this issue?

THX

Answer (score 0):

The SOS_SCHEDULER_YIELD wait type occurs when a task is waiting for cpu time. This usually indicates something ***else*** is consuming CPU time that this task would like to use instead. You could kill off the other task, but that's harsh, you could stuff in more CPU, but that's expensive, you could set MAXDOP for your update statement so it doesn't use try to use the CPUs that are otherwise occupied, but that can result in longer execution times (or shorter).

The **short** answer is: Something's in your base stealing your CPU.

The **long** answer is to do thorough analysis, and that's a bit beyond scope based on the information you have provided.

Comment: Really appreciate your quick response:) So the cup value means hos long this query has been waiting for being executed?

Comment: And how to set MAXDOP for update statement? I only know how to set MAXDOP to the instance

Comment: I'd say how long it's been waiting for the scheduler to give the task cpu time.

Comment: For Query Hints (MAXDOP) - see MSDN: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181714.aspx